# Four layer board in Altium Designer, the power and ground layer is shown without copper pour

Tags: pcb

I have made a four layer board using Altium Designer, while viewing the gerber files in the gerber viewer (Gerbv viewing software) for the power plane and the ground plane, I am unable to see the copper pour I am only able to see the slots for through-hole via and micro vias. After that I called Altium re-seller and he told me that it is the native format, if you are not seeing the copper it means there is copper in it. I have attached images below, but I am unable to get the why there are no copper pour in the power and ground plane, if I give it for PCB manufacturing will the copper pour be there in the Ground and Power plane.

[image: Top Layer]
Top Layer
[image: Power Plane]
Power Plane
[image: Ground Plane]
Ground Plane
[image: Bottom Layer]
Bottom Layer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Altium Power Plane Gerber inverted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213149/altium-power-plane-gerber-inverted)

Comment: Looks normal to me

Answer (score 1):

The plane layers are usually drawn in negative (not native) format - what you see is "not-copper".  The board shop does the necessary magic to ensure that there is copper everywhere on the plane layer, except where there is something shown on the Gerber artwork.